# UIImage always returns null after re-installing the app

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I'm testing my app on an iPhone 6s. This question has already been asked here but the recommended solutions do not seem to work for me. I'm working with Monotouch (c#).

I save the image like this:

```
var documentsDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
string jpgFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsDirectory,"photo.jpg");
NSData imgData = image.AsJPEG();
NSError err = null;
if (imgData.Save(jpgFilename, false, out err))
{
    userProfile.ImageFilePath = jpgFilename;

    Console.WriteLine("saved as " + jpgFilename);
}
else {
    Console.WriteLine("NOT saved as" + jpgFilename + " because" + err.LocalizedDescription);
}
```

Then in the `ViewWillAppear` of a different `UIViewController`, I try to load it like this:

```
var documentsDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
string localFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsDirectory, "photo.jpg");

UIImage savedImage = UIImage.FromFile(localFile);

if (savedImage != null)
{

    imgPhoto.Image = savedImage;
}
```

Unfortunately, my `savedImage` is always null after I re-install the app. Testing in debug mode.

Anyone know the solution for Xamarin.iOS?

**Edit**

I have learnt that I should not be saving absolute paths to my app data directory. I should only save relative paths (relative to the app's directory). The problem is that the path of the app (the GUID) changes each time.So the image is null because it's been moved.

so this GUID in the path is different each time i re-install the app.

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/637F7758-5102-4328-9969-A4ED3826139E/Documents/photo.jpg.
```

How do I save the correct relative path?

Comment: By "re-installing", do you mean that you delete the application from the simulator yourself before starting a new debugging session?

Comment: Yes. I delete the app from my device and start a new debugging session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking is not possible. When uninstalling the application between debugging session, the [application sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html) is removed as mentioned [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63162/are-there-leftover-files-when-i-uninstall-an-iphone-app).

If you on the other hand didn't uninstall the application between debugging sessions, the data you stored in `Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal` would still be available.

As a note, and as you have observed yourself, the GUID of the application sandbox changes in-between debugging sessions. The content is although simply copied over to the new directory. This means you won't lose data in-between sessions.

### Use iCloud Document Storage

Instead, what you should consider is to use the [Document Storage for iCloud](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_icloud/#Document_Storage). This will allow you to save data to iCloud, uninstall the application, and lastly load the given data once the application is installed once more.

Although, if you decide to utilise this approach, a few requirements exist as mentioned [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_icloud/#Preparing_for_iCloud_development).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that the documents in this folder, along with all the other App's data were being deleted. That answered my question. I tested the function again, in the same session and it does work.